# Return the line to its original position after making a Requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I apologize for my English is a Google translation.

This is a question that I have had a hard time with for a long time and in all the places that have been talked about it remains unanswered, so I am publishing my solution for the benefit of all.

Sometimes you are required to refresh the source of the form (in continuous form) and then you use let's say a bookmark to return to the record you were before the refresh, the problem is that if we say the form now shows you records 40-60 and you stand on record 45, when you return to 45 after refresh it is not The fifth will be displayed on the screen but it will be the first, which may cause confusion for the user, I have always looked for a way to return the same record that will be the fifth on the screen and the user will not see any change.

I found that it is possible to use the "CurrentSectionTop" property, it means where you are located in relation to the top edge of the form, you need to lower the height of the header from it.

Below is the code:

```
Const MaxRecordInViwe = 50
Const ValuePerLine = 564

MySelTop = Me.SelTop
CurrentRowInViwe = (Me.CurrentSectionTop - Me.FormHeader.Height) / ValuePerLine

Me.Requery

Me.SelTop = (MySelTop - MyCurrentRowInViwe) + MaxRecordInViwe
Me.SelTop = MySelTop - MyCurrentRowInViwe
Me.SelTop = MySelTop
```

If your screen has more than 50 entries, you will change the default "MaxRecordInViwe", if you enter less you can leave it unchanged.
The constant "ValuePerLine" fits my form, I did not find a formula to calculate it but you can find it manually:

- Go to the first record
- In the Immediate window, type the following code:

  `?Form_table1.CurrentSectionTop - Form_Table1.FormHeader.Height`
- In the form, go to the second entry
- In the Immediate window, type the following code:

  `?(Form_table1.CurrentSectionTop- Form_Table1.FormHeader.Height)- {The previous result})`
- Enter the result to set "ValuePerLine"

Comment: Also explore Recordset.Requery method.

Comment: You should first ask a question and then post your answer. It is confusing as is if this is a question or an answer.

Comment: I did not know about the Recordset.Requery method, it does do the job great.
However when you need to change the "RecordSource" property of the form (for example in filtering) it will not help.